# Control ipad apps from pc via bluetooth/wifi

Tags: iphone, ipad, bluetooth, wifi

I would like to create an iPhone/iPad application and interface that will control a device from PC via Wifi/bluetooth. Just wanted to know whether it is possible and if yes, how? Is it possible to send commands to device over wifi?

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Check [NSStream](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/&ei=i2o2To6TFdCgOuO_4f4L&usg=AFQjCNE6zxtoB8NGgAjJb3J0MF2YQwz5Qg&sig2=L79gfFMCs7RHrokcUjLDxQ) and the subclasses [NSInputStream](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html&ei=rWo2TvqoIoiCOrPnldoL&usg=AFQjCNFy4FkK503rBbXEl115a5VXI2TtKg&sig2=RYE7QO99fdodmFzLxgdESw) and [NSOutputStream](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSOutputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html&ei=x2o2TvM1jZU6xard8gs&usg=AFQjCNEnyNs-F-vmCtCkiD1Bz48r0wdEEA&sig2=sq_fH21jxXdeXEM1OFQvcw) to send data over wifi.

To use bluetooth you may refer to [Bluetooth Device Access Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/Bluetooth/BT_Intro/BT_Intro.html)